# Application size won't change in iCloud after do not backup flag is set

Tags: ios, backup

I have found several similar questions:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859166/do-not-backup-flag-for-ios-5-1)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316082/apps-must-follow-the-ios-data-storage-guidelines-nothing-in-documents-but-stil)

I have added code as described in link2:
I call this method after picture download and saving in directory.

```
-(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == NULL) {
    // Use iOS 5.0.1 mechanism

    const char *filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char *attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
else {
    // Use NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey mechanism, iOS 5.1+
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                                  forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                                   error:&error];
    if(!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Path is %@:", [URL path]);
    }
    //Check your error and take appropriate action
    return success;
}
```

}

When checking in iCloud the size of application is still 50.7 Mb (I'm testing on iPhone with 5.1.1 iOS version), so using of flag didn't have any effect, although success has a "YES" value. 
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you purged iCloud for your app and started over? If the file is already in iCloud and you then update the flag, it may have no effect.

Comment: I have tried this: delete app, switch off back up in iCloud, switch on back up in iCloud. Then I install app again, download data, check iCloud, and data is still in iCloud.

Comment: When I delete app, switch off back up in iCloud, switch on back up in iCloud, then install app again and go to iCloud, I can see my application and in data size field is written no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in method for making URL of file path. Currently I've changed to + fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: and everything works great. Size for my application in iCloud storage is shown as 0.9KB (previosly it was 50.7Mb).